# can't create directory with docker CLI in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

i want compile source code from github after clone in jenkins, I running jenkins in Docker DIND, but I got problem when I compile with command `docker run -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/nodejs-app:/app -w /app node:alpine npm i` i got error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoen
```

[image]

sample Dockerfile Jenkins

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -qqy apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common 
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    stable"
RUN apt-get update  -qq \
    && apt-get install docker-ce -y
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Sample docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    build: .
    container_name: 'jenkins-container'
    privileged: true
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    volumes:
       - jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '50000:50000'

volumes:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
  jenkins_data:
```

if I running in local, it's work, but not work in jenkins

thank you.